# Select most popular tags from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables linked together through the 3rd table

```
threads: id, name
tags: id, name
thread_tag_map: threads_id, tags_id
```

Its a many to many relationship. I want to select 30 tags that are most popular that is to say the first 30 tags with `tags_id` which occur the most in `thread_tag_map`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.*
FROM
  tags t
JOIN
  thread_tag_map ttm ON t.id = ttm.tags_id
GROUP BY
  t.id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(t.id) DESC
LIMIT 30
```